# Assign bin value according to vector of thresholds

Tags: r, data.table

I have a vector of thresholds that I want to use for creating bins of a column on a data.table

```
thrshlds <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.05)
test <- data.table(
  A = rnorm(1000, 0.7, 1),
  B = rbinom(1000, 3, 0.6)
)
```

The logic that I'm looking to implement is:

If the value of column A is equal or less than the value of each threshold, then assign it its respective threshold value. Similar to a SQL *case when*, but without manually assigning each threshold value.

Something like:

```
test[, new_category := fcase(A <= thrshlds[1], thrshlds[1],
                             A <= thrshlds[2], thrshlds[2],
                             .....)]
```

But I don't know how to do this kind of iteration inside a data.table query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cut` :

```
library(data.table)
test[, new_category := cut(A, c(-Inf, thrshlds), thrshlds)]
test

#                 A B new_category
#   1:  0.220744413 3         0.25
#   2: -0.814886795 3            0
#   3:  1.134536656 2         <NA>
#   4:  0.180463333 1          0.2
#   5: -0.134559033 1            0
#  ---                            
# 996: -0.332559649 1            0
# 997:  0.585641110 0          0.6
# 998:  0.765738832 2          0.8
# 999:  2.167632026 2         <NA>
#1000:  0.008935421 2         0.05
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is an appropriate method or not, but here's a rolling join option that seems to work:

```
test[, new_category := data.table(thrshlds)[test, on="thrshlds==A", x.thrshlds, roll=-Inf] ]

#test[sample(1000, 12)]
#             A B new_category
# 1: -1.1317742 3         0.00
# 2:  0.2926608 2         0.30
# 3:  1.5441214 2           NA
# 4:  0.9249706 1         0.95
# 5:  1.2663975 2           NA
# 6:  0.6472989 0         0.65
# 7: -0.5606153 2         0.00
# 8:  0.4439064 2         0.45
# 9:  0.8182938 1         0.85
#10:  0.8461909 2         0.85
#11:  1.0237554 1           NA
#12:  0.7752323 1         0.80
```